# ansible lineinfile: add line in a certain place if absent from entire file

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to create a playbook that will add a line to a file in a specific place if that line is completely absent from the file, but if the line exists anywhere, it does not get added at all.

For example, if the line I want to add is "bar", and the line I want to add after is "foo" I may have 3 files:

**file1**

```
foo
bar
baz
```

**file2**

```
foo
baz
```

**file3**

```
foo
baz
bar
```

In `file2`, "bar" would be added after "foo".  But "bar" is already present in `file1` and `file3`, so it should not be added, even though in `file3`, it is not immediately after "foo".

I've tried this:

```
- name: Change File
  lineinfile:
    path: /path/to/file
    line: bar
    insertafter: ^foo$
```

The problem is with this playbook, if I ruin it on `file3`, I end up with

```
foo
bar
baz
bar
```

It just checks the `insertafter`, and if the `line` isn't immediately after that line, it adds it there.

How can I get what I want?

Comment: This is due to changes which were inconsistent with past behaviour, docs, and [are disputed in the community as a bug](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/38655).

Answer (score 2):

I needed a  `regexp` line:

```
- name: Change File
  lineinfile:
    path: /path/to/file
    line: bar
    regexp: ^bar$
    insertafter: ^foo$
```